# Get posts by Wordpress user display name via MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a search form in Wordpress that searches all posts titles, content, and custom fields in a custom post type.  It won't search by author though.  I'd like if the search keyword matches a display name to go ahead and also output any posts by that author.

Here's my current code (the display_name part of it is obviously wrong, but illustrates what I want to accomplish).  Everything works except for the get posts by display_name part.  Any help or guidance is appreciated :)

```
// Code originally modified 
// from http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2012/04/search-all-custom-fields.html

global $wpdb;
// Gets the ?crs= search from the submitted form
$keyword = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['crs'] );
$keyword = '%' . like_escape( $keyword ) . '%'; 

// Search in all custom fields
$post_ids_meta = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
    WHERE meta_value LIKE '%s'
", $keyword ) );

// Search in post_title and post_content
$post_ids_post = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    WHERE post_title LIKE '%s'
    OR post_content LIKE '%s'
", $keyword, $keyword ) );

// Search in User Table for Display Name
// This is where I'm not sure what how to get the posts by display_name
$post_ids_user = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM {$wpdb->users}
    WHERE display_name LIKE '%s'
", $keyword ) );

$post_ids = array_merge( $post_ids_meta, $post_ids_post, $post_ids_user );

// Query arguments for WP_Query
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'courses',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'limit' => '',
    'post__in'    => $post_ids,
);
```

Comment: As far as I see, and as far as I remember it should be written as  `%%keyword%%`. **%%** is escape sequence for, and parsed as **%**. `$wpdb->prepare` will parse it correctly then. This is at first sight.

Comment: Do you mean in this section?  I'm not sure what you're referring to or why it helps.  Sorry for my lack of knowledge here :)
'$post_ids_user = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM {$wpdb->users}
    WHERE display_name LIKE '%s'
", $keyword ) );'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing i would like to suggest instead of running multiple queries join your tables and work around in a go

> SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM {$wpdb->users}
>       WHERE display_name LIKE '%s' this is wrong query you cannot get the post ids from users table ,relation of posts and user is maintained in the posts table and each post contains user id in `post_author` column

Try this one

```
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT p.ID FROM $wpdb->posts p
INNER JOIN $wpdb->users u ON (p.`post_author` = u.`ID`)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta m ON (p.`ID`= m.`post_id`)
WHERE ( u.display_name LIKE '%s' OR p.post_title LIKE '%s' 
OR p.post_content LIKE '%s' OR m.meta_value LIKE '%s')
GROUP BY p.`ID`
", $keyword ) );

//print_r($post_ids); //you will get the post ids
$post_ids=array_values(array_unique($post_ids));
```

Comment: Doing them all in one search would be amazing - thanks for guiding me on that.  I deleted everything from //search all custom fields to immediately before // Query arguments for WP_Query, and replaced it with your code.  For the array that was output, everything had this value though:  => 1

Comment: @Jerry for `post__in` you need an array of ids like `array('1','2'..)` ,just get ids from `$post_ids` using loop and fetch your posts

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear with my previous comment.  I have a loop running afterwards that is using the data correctly.  However, when I use the code you wrote above, I don't get the right results. There are no results, even for the right searches.  I set-up a demo of your code compared to the one I posted originally. www.permacourses.com/?crs=overflow is the original with search, and www.permacourses.com/stack-overflow/?crs=overflow is yours with a search for the keyword overflow.  Results are print_r'd in the source.  Thanks again for your time on this!

Comment: @Jerry can you show your whole code with the loop without seeing anything i can't guess whats wrong

Comment: I set-up a git repo here so I don't accidentally leave anything out that you need :) https://github.com/jeryj/permacourses

The filenames that you need to look at are content-googlemap.php and content-googlemapstackoverflow.php. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for sticking with me on this :)  I updated the code, and there are no more repeat values, but the value it is grabbing is incorrect.  If I were just to modify $post_ids_user from my original post, what would be the correct way to grab the posts by a matched display name?  Would that help us to figure out where the issue is?

Comment: For this you need something like `$post_ids_user = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT DISTINCT p.ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->users u ON (p.post_author = u.ID)
    WHERE u.display_name LIKE '%s'
", $keyword ) );`

Comment: That works! Thanks!  I wonder why it's not working as a joined query?

Comment: @Jerry don't know :) and please accept this answer if you feel it works